# Doing a while loop over guessing game

Tags: javascript, html

I've run into something that I can't seem to figure out. I'm trying to make it loop, so when the user guesses the right info, it breaks the loop. But if they continue to get it wrong, it'll say "Wanna play again". Here's my code:

```
while (userResponse="yes") {        

            var value = 15;
            var guess = prompt('Please enter a number greater than zero.');

                if (value == guess) {
                    alert ('The number you entered was correct. You won!');
                }else if (guess == null){
                    alert ('You didn\'t enter anything!');                  
                }else if ((guess > value + 0)){
                    alert ('You\'re way off!');
                }else if ((guess <= value + 7) && (guess >= value - 7)){
                    alert ('You\'re getting warm!');
                }else if ((guess > value + 7)  || (guess < value - 7)){
                    alert ('You\'re getting cold!');                
                } else {
                    alert ('Something went wrong.');
                }
                userResponse = prompt("Would you like to play again?");
        }
```

any ideas on what it is that I'm doing wrong? All I want to do is when the user guesses "15" it dies automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong before addressing the loop:

1. Replace the infinite loop for a function that you call when you want to ask the question.
2. `userResponse="yes"` will *ALWAYS* return true, you probably want `userResponse=="yes"`

To quit from the loop when the user guesses the response you just need to do `break`([break on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).